# How to lookup and validate foreign keys in new.html.erb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My data model is that a student is associated with a teacher. My student entry form will have a teacher username field, which I want to validate against an existing teacher record. How will I accomplish this in the app/view/student/new.html.erb file? Right now, I just have this:

```
<tr>
 <th>Teacher ID</th>
 <td><%= f.number_field :teacher_id %></td>
</tr>
```

I want to make this the :teacher_username and then validate against the teachers table. if a match is found, I want to get the teachers.id field and pass it on for insert into the student table. If a match is not found, then I want to flag an error that no such teacher username exists. How can I accomplish this. Any sample code would be helpful.

The student model file has belongs_to :teacher in it. The teacher model file has has_many :students in it.

Comment: How about displaying the teachers in a select box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@Iceman** suggested,a `drop-down` box is appropriate for your purpose.

In your `/views/student/new.html.erb` you can do this

```
<tr>
 <th>Select Teacher</th>
 <td><%= f.select :teacher_id,Teacher.all.collect {|t| [ t.teacher_username, t.id ] },{ include_blank: true } %></td>
</tr>
```

This will ensure that only the `records` that are present in `teachers table` will be available here in the `drop-down` and simplifies the `validation` part which you are looking.

Comment: Pavan that sounds like a good idea and thanks for the code example.  Anyway to have a text box where  we type in and the matching entries are listed as we type? Or is that too fantastic to happen in rails

Comment: @gvermag You are talking about text box with autocomplete.Yes its possible!

Comment: @gvermag Have a look at this https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete It is what you want.

Comment: @Pavan will rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem work with Rails4.x. I am using Rails4.

Comment: @Pavan  It seems that this fork https://github.com/francisd/rails3-jquery-autocomplete is supposed to work with Rails4. They didnt update the README but changed the gemspec file. What I dont understand is that the installation instruction of fork is also the same as the standard gem, so how would you install the fork's code.

Comment: @Pavan I found http://rubydoc.info/gems/rails4-autocomplete/1.0.7/frames and will be trying it out. Will update the thread with the results.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make this the :teacher_username and then validate against
>   the teachers table. if a match is found, I want to get the teachers.id
>   field and pass it on for insert into the student table. If a match is
>   not found, then I want to flag an error that no such teacher username
>   exists. How can I accomplish this. Any sample code would be helpful.

You may need to look at [**ActiveRecord validations**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

More specifically, I'd do somthing *like* this:

```
#app/models/teacher.rb
Class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    vaidates :username, uniqueness: true
end
```

I mention "like" because you want to pass the details to your `student` table. If you're doing this with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), then it's okay; however if you're not, then you may wish to divulge your process, so we can help you define it

--

**Update**

Having read your question more thoroughly, it seems you're trying to look up a teacher's username, then if it exists, pass the `id` back to the `student` table

A [`drop down`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) will probably be the best option for this, however if you wanted to look up the name, you'd have to call an action on the `students` controller to validate the username via ajax, like:

```
#app/controllers/students_controller.rb
def check_teacher
    teacher = Teacher.find_by username: params[:userame]
end
```

But having read the question properly, I'd recommend the drop down